# Input type=color won't change

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, input

I have been working on some kind of blog script for the last few couple of weeks, and I am stuck on this.

Basically the user should be able to change the color of the background of the blog. So I added the new HTML5 color input:

```
<input type="color" name="bgcolor">
```

Then I pulled the former color from the MySQL database of my client and set it to the value of my color input:

```
..."bgcolor" value="<?php $query = "SELECT * FROM `config` WHERE `config`.`id` = '1'";
                          $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                          $array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                           echo $array['bgcolor']; ?>">
```

It works fine and I can see the color on the color input when I visit the Site Config page, but I can't change the color. No matter what color I pick it always sticks to the color from the database unless I change it manually. But the weird thing is I can just change the color and save it to the database when I remove the `value="<?php...?>"` part. I just don't want it to reset to black so my client accidentally forgets to set the background color and it turns to black.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest separating your view and controller logic. And even more so, I'd suggest not using `mysql_*` because it has been **deprecated** and is no longer supported in versions > PHP 5.5

Comment: When there is no color value coming from DB it sets black backgoround?

Comment: Where is the code that saves the selected color to the database? And how do these three parts fit together?

Comment: @Oswald The code basically checks if an hidden input called "sent" isset, if it is, it UPDATEs the values of the config table WHERE config.id is 1. It works fine when I don't add the value="<?php?>" part.

Comment: @christopher what should I use instead of them? Thanks

Comment: @EhsanSajjad there is a color value coming from the DB #00A000 but I cannot change the color value.

Comment: @mission712 You have two options. Either the `mysqli_*` functionality, or the `PDO` object. Personally, I prefer the `PDO` object. You can read up on the `PDO` object [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: @christopher thank you. I prefer `mysqli_*` functionality more, mosly because it has similarities with `mysql_*`.